# How can I clear a selected radio button in WatiN?

Tags: watin

I have a long form to test, so I created a CompleteForm() helper method to complete the form. To test the validations, I am calling CompleteForm() and then making the field I want to test invalid. Can't figure out how to uncheck the radiobuttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `Checked` property of the `RadioButton` object to `false`

To uncheck all the radio buttons on a page you could do:

```
foreach(RadioButton rb in ie.RadioButtons)
{       
    rb.Checked = false
}
```

Comment: I just found the comments feature. Thanks for your help; I new it would be something stupidly simple.